# Слово "ряженка"

Tags: этимология

От какого слова происходит слово "ряженка"? "Ряженые" (или "ряженные"?)?  Но почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точной этимологии нет, но если предполагать родство с "ряд/ряж", то скорее не с "ряжеными" (разодевшиеся, раскрашенными), а с "рядом", "зарядом". По технологии "ряженку" как бы заряжают специальной закваской. При этом происходит уникальный процесс - начальное створаживание сладкомолочного продукта (густого топлёного молока). Нечто подобное получается при образовании пенок при кипячении, но пенки - это совершенно другой продукт.

Есть и другие версии.
~1. Пришло из литовского или латышского. Вот одно из таких объяснений:
*Слово ряженка происходит от латышского ‘подкислять, прокисать’ raûdzêt (-êju) 'säuern'. Завезено из Курляндии*. Было бы провдоподобно, если бы не главное: ряженка - продукт **сладкомолочный**. Её часто путают с варенцом, отсюда и попытка объяснить через "кислый" (варенец - изделие киcломолочное).

~2. На самом деле она - рыженка. Остроумно, но не более.

~3. Связано с ряжа, ряжка - чан. Самое правдоподобное.

~4. Выводят из "sъtvarožiti", откуда и творог. Сомнительно. "Творог" - слово польское, а в Польше, насколько мне известно, и на западной Украине ряженка не слишком популярна, там в ходу именно варенец, хотя, как сказал, эти продукты часто путают.

(использованы материалы лингвофорума)

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто.

На самом деле происхождение слова идет от слова "пряжить" - др.-русский - *жарить, печь,*

что находит подтверждение в технологии приготовления, ведь продукт - это не что иное, как молоко со сливками, запеченное в горшочках, и только потом заквашено, а не заряжено. :p

Comment: -1.
Ряженка не заквашивается. 
"Пряжить", "пряжение" - вид жарки, обязательно на масле (как и вообще всякая жарка).
О том, как могло пропасть П в начаое слова, даже не спрашиваю.

Comment: вот вы мне, инженеру-технологу, будете рассказывать не заквашивается
лучше почитайте ГОСТ
http://www.ecomash.ru/account/329/334/
а про букву "П" так примеров потери букв в словах и даже в корнях слов уйма.

Comment: Ряженка не заквашивается в истинном смысле слова. Это факт. По ссылке - сайт производителя оборудования. "Закваска" есть, но она не заквашивает, а створаживает, то есть это не закваска в истинном смысле слова. ... Боже ж, в Вики такая же чушь. Ну я умываю руки...

Answer (score 0):

Ряженка - от украинского "пряжити" (томить в духовке). "Пряжене молоко" - это по-украински "топленое молоко", с которого и делается "пряжанка" - то, что русское ухо услышало как "ряженка".

Comment: Почему *"пряжанка"*? 

По-украински просто *"ряжанка"*. Вот перед мной сейчас банка с такой надписью, из украинского супермаркета.

А *топлёное молоко* -- это действительно *"пряжене молоко"*.

Comment: 
![alt text][1]


  [1]: https://test.org.ua/uploads/2012/Ryazhenka%20%2812%29/Voloshkove_pole_01.jpg

Comment: Вернусь к этой теме.

Попались мне непроверенные сведения, что кое-где в укр.селах говорят *"пряженка"/пряжанка*. То есть на разговорном уровне, вариант слова, которое выше привел @Павло, может быть.

Встретилась и версия происхождения *ряженка <- пряжанка <- пряжене молоко*. НО! Утверждается, что это так называемая "народная этимология".